# is there an emacs tool to show a directory structure as a tree?

Tags: emacs, dired

I am aware of Speedbar (I prefer the structure in the same frame as the rest of my work), and dired shows too much information. I'm after something like the svn-status tree representation. Is there anything like that?
Thank you.

**EDIT**: Here's what I found the most intuitive:

I am using `Speedbar` with the following hack from [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar#toc2). I had to use the commented "try this" part, FYI.

```
  (require 'speedbar)
  (defconst my-speedbar-buffer-name "SPEEDBAR")
  ; (defconst my-speedbar-buffer-name " SPEEDBAR") ; try this if you get "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil"
  (defun my-speedbar-no-separate-frame ()
    (interactive)
    (when (not (buffer-live-p speedbar-buffer))
      (setq speedbar-buffer (get-buffer-create my-speedbar-buffer-name)
            speedbar-frame (selected-frame)
            dframe-attached-frame (selected-frame)
            speedbar-select-frame-method 'attached
            speedbar-verbosity-level 0
            speedbar-last-selected-file nil)
      (set-buffer speedbar-buffer)
      (speedbar-mode)
      (speedbar-reconfigure-keymaps)
      (speedbar-update-contents)
      (speedbar-set-timer 1)
      (make-local-hook 'kill-buffer-hook)
      (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook
                (lambda () (when (eq (current-buffer) speedbar-buffer)
                             (setq speedbar-frame nil
                                   dframe-attached-frame nil
                                   speedbar-buffer nil)
                             (speedbar-set-timer nil)))))
    (set-window-buffer (selected-window) 
                       (get-buffer my-speedbar-buffer-name)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [**tree extension**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander#toc8) for emacs mode [Sunrise Commander](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander). Sunrise Commander is like Midnight Commander.

Answer (score 6):

So I wanted to just print a tree quickly and all Emacs based solutions seemed either rather old or massive like (ECB/CEDET) which I don't know enough about, so for quick fix I did

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

then from dired buffer

```
M-! tree --dirsfirst RET
```

voilà! directory tree without any specific libs, as an added bonus using `tree -f` outputs tree with full paths, making it obvious to jump to file with `C-x C-f` directly from the tree output buffer.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [Emacs Code Browser](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsCodeBrowser). Last I heard using it with a current emacs may be tricky or difficult because it makes use of some tools that were recently integrated into Emacs via [CEDET](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollectionOfEmacsDevelopmentEnvironmentTools).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [NeoTree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree). It's easy to install and easy to use.

[image: NeoTree screenshot, from EmacsWiki]